# How can I give SQL Server permission to read my SSL Key?

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

I recently created a self-signed certificate and turned encryption on in SQL Server 2014:

[image: self signed cert]

The problem is that now the SQL Server service won't start:

[image: startup error]

[This article](https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/sql-ssl-and-sql-server-2008-service-doesnt-start-error-code-2146885628/) from 2010 identifies the problem as a permissions issue: The SQL Server service does not have the necessary permission to read the SSL cert's private key.

The problem is that I am stuck on step 4 of the solution proposed in the article:

[image: stuck on step 4]

There is no group or user name matching the proposed format when I bring up the window shown in the article.

Is there another way I can determine the account that SQL Server service runs under, so that I can give it permissions to read the SSL cert?

An entirely different solution is welcome too.

Comment: Which account you use for SQL Server windows service? I suppose that you have problem to access to the Private Key of the certificate in `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`. You can open MMC, add Certificate Snap-In, choose Computer, find the SQL Server certificate in Personal, select the certificate and choose "Manage Private Keys" context menu. After that you should grant permission to the account, which you use to run SQL Server.

Comment: I forget to mention that Read access for the account should be enough.

Comment: How do I find which account I use for the SQL Server service?

Comment: @Oleg, fwiw, under "Permission for Self Signed Cert" window, there are the 3 users/groups listed -- SYSTEM, Administrators, and Account Unknown -- and all 3 have at least Read permissions.  As I said, I do now know which, if any, of these accounts runs the SQL Server service, nor do I know how to find out.

Comment: You should just start `services.msc`, find SQL Server service, examine the account name like `NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2014` and you should grant Read permission to the account.

Comment: No such account name is listed there.  Here is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/UY9y6CF.png

Comment: One can see `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` on the picture. You should  grant Read permission to the account with respect of "Manage Private Keys" context menu of the Certificate SnapIn.

Comment: Thanks again!  I got it started after adding the user MSSQLSERVER.  If you add that as the answer I'll accept tomorrow.  Also, do you have any advice for exposing sql server to the world in a secure way?

Comment: I'll do this. I'm afraid, that I can't give advices about exposing SQL Server to the world because I don't have such experience.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you specify the certificate, which should be used for TLS by SQL Server, then the SQL Server windows service have to read the certificate *and the private key* (the file from the folder `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`), which corresponds the certificate. The problem is: **the SQL Server Configuration Manager in not comfortable and it makes not all the required work**.

Thus first of all one should localize the Account used by SQL Server. One should start `services.msc`, find the account of SQL Server service. It's typically a build-in account like `Local System`, `Network Service` a local or domain account like `.\SQLServer`, `DOMAIN\SQLServerAccount` or an service account like `NT Service\NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2012` on the picture below:

[image]

To grant permission on the private key to the account one can use Certificate Snap-In of mmc. One can start `mmc.exe`, choose "Add/Remove Snap-in" in the "File" menu, choose "Certificates" Snap-in and to choose "Computer account" of the Local computer. Then one should select the SSL certificate of Personal store and then use context menu "Manage Private Keys...".

[image]

and to add account like `NT Service\NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2012`, found above, and to set "Read" permission to the account on the private key:

[image]

If you would like to establish connection to the SQL server inside of the domain (both the client and the server have to belong to the same Active Directory or to the directories connected via the trust) then one should to create SPNs for the SQL server. If I correctly understand your requirements, you want to allow **remove** connection to SQL Server over HTTPS. One have to active mixed security to be able to connect to the server via SQL Server Authentication:

[image]

After creating SQL Login, making all above changed and restarting SQL Server service one will be able to establish TLS (encrypted) connection to the SQL server. In case of attempting to connect via Windows Account without creating SPN previously one get the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: -2146893022)
>
> The target principal name is incorrect

[image]

If one forget to change Windows Authentication to Mixed authentication () then one will get the error like

> Login failed for user 'OlegKi'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

[image]

If all above steps done one can establish TLS connection using SQL Management Studio for example, but one still have to choose some options:

[image]

One should check "Encrypt connection"

[image]

and to set additional connection property `TrustServerCertificate=true`

Typically one use `Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;` as the part of connection string in the application which establish the connection to SQL server. We set `Encrypt=true` property by the checkbox "Encrypt connection" describe above. More detailed about the meaning of the properties and different combinations of the options can be read in "Enabling Encryption" section of [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx).

If one do all the above steps and check "Encrypt connection" without setting `TrustServerCertificate=true` property then one will get the error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: -2146893022)
>
> The target principal name is incorrect

[image]

which I already described above in a little another situation (connection with Windows account).

I described all above steps because configuration of TLS connection to the server is really not so easy and one can get strange errors, which direct description gives no direct tips how to fix the problem.

Comment: Amazing answer!  Wish I could upvote 10 times.  I will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: @Jonah: You are welcome! Please inform me about the final results. I updated my previous answer too. I hope you will be able to use the **original SSL certificate** too. The problem with self-signed certificate is the trust. One have to add it **on all clients** as Trusted Root certificate. Because of that one don't use the way in any real scenarios.

Comment: The part with "set "Read" permission to the account on the private key" helped in my case! I struggled for 9 days untill I tried to run the service from local system account and it worked, so I understood that my issue was about permissions. Then I found this solution! Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

One other note: If you are entering the certificate thumbprint into the registry manually by copying and pasting from the certificate manager, you must remove the leading character. It is an invisible unicode character, but it will cause the SQL Server service to be unable to start if it is present. This is in addition to making it ALL CAPS, and removing all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. What i was doing was:

Importing the certificate from the sql server protocol properties dialog, using the 'import' button. I imported the public key, then another open dialog opened to import the private keys. I then set the private key permission to the sql server service.
When importing a key pair directly, such as a .pfx bundle, the application crashed.
All permissions to MachineKeys were granted as well for the sql serive, but I could not find through process monitor any access denied for that path.

In order to solve my issue, i imported the pfx directly from the explorer. I first removed the key pair from the store, then I ran through the wizard to import the pfx in the local machine store, personal folder. I checked the permissions on the private key, they were still set for the sql service. I checked the protocol properties, the certificate was already selected. Only then the server started.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that certificate must have server and client authentication in intended purposes (Extended key usage) and of course the private key access to the account under which SQL is running.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to fix the same error. New certificate was generated, but it configuration wasn't adjusted in SQL.

I just went to regedit and changed the thumbprint there and made sure that all the necessary permissions are added.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).