# Replace SSL Certificate on Remote IIS 10 server from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssl, iis, x509certificate2, web-administration

I'm attempting to automate the process of renewing my SSL certificates for a few different publicly accessible endpoints. I'm using [Certify the Web](https://certifytheweb.com/)'s **Certify SSL/TLS Certificate Management** to complete the CSR and SSL generation and validation via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Certify DNS](https://docs.certifytheweb.com/docs/dns/providers/certifydns/). This generates the `.pfx` files, which are then copied across the network to a location where my main "daily processing" application can access them and try to install them. I've been able to successfully get that application to install the certificates to the remote servers' certificate stores, but I'm unable to get the IIS 10 bindings reconfigured on the sites to use the new certificates.

For reference, here's the code for installing the certificate in the remote server's certificate store, which seems to work perfectly:

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Web.Administration

Private Sub AddCertificateToRemoteStore(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal StoreName As String, ByVal Certificate As X509Certificate2)
    If HostName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("HostName", "You must specify a server hostname")
    ElseIf StoreName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(StoreName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("StoreName", "You must specify a certificate store name")
    ElseIf Certificate Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Certificate", "A valid X509Certificate2 object is required")
    Else
        Dim CertStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\{1}", HostName, StoreName)
        Dim RootStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\Root", HostName)
        Dim IntermediateStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\CA", HostName)

        Using CertChain As New X509Chain
            If CertChain.Build(Certificate) Then
                Dim FindResults As X509Certificate2Collection
                Dim StorePermissions As New StorePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)

                With StorePermissions
                    .Flags = StorePermissionFlags.OpenStore Or StorePermissionFlags.AddToStore
                    .Assert()
                End With

                For C = 0 To CertChain.ChainElements.Count - 1
                    If C = 0 Then
                        Using CertificateStore As New X509Store(CertStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With CertificateStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using
                    ElseIf C = CertChain.ChainElements.Count - 1 Then
                        Using RootStore As New X509Store(RootStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With RootStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using
                    Else
                        Using IntermediateStore As New X509Store(IntermediateStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With IntermediateStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using
                    End If
                Next C
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

With the certificate successfully added to the store (I've verified that it's there through `certlm.msc`), the next obvious step is to apply the new certificate to the existing IIS 10 site's bindings so it can actually be used for SSL/TLS communication. Here's what I'm currently using to try to accomplish that with the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace:

```vb
Private Sub ApplyCertificateBinding(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal StoreName As String, ByVal ActiveCertificate As X509Certificate2)
    If HostName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("HostName", "You must specify a server hostname")
    ElseIf StoreName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(StoreName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("StoreName", "You must specify a certificate store name")
    ElseIf ActiveCertificate Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("ActiveCertificate", "A valid X509Certificate2 object is required")
    Else
        Dim SSLSiteName As String = ActiveCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, False)
        Dim HostSites As New List(Of Site)

        Using HostManager As ServerManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(HostName)
            For Each Site As Site In HostManager.Sites
                If Site.Name = SSLSiteName Then
                    HostSites.Add(Site)
                Else
                    For Each Binding In Site.Bindings
                        If Binding.Host = SSLSiteName Then
                            HostSites.Add(Site)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next Binding
                End If
            Next Site

            For Each Site As Site In HostSites
                For Each SiteBinding In Site.Bindings
                    If SiteBinding.Protocol = "https" Then
                        Dim NewBinding As Binding = Site.Bindings.CreateElement

                        NewBinding.CertificateStoreName = StoreName
                        NewBinding.Protocol = "https"
                        NewBinding.CertificateHash = ActiveCertificate.GetCertHash
                        NewBinding.BindingInformation = SiteBinding.BindingInformation

                        SiteBinding = NewBinding
                        HostManager.CommitChanges()
                    End If
                Next SiteBinding

                Site.Stop()
                
                'PROBABLY A BETTER WAY TO HANDLE THIS 
                Do While Site.State <> ObjectState.Stopped
                Loop

                Site.Start()

                'AND THIS
                Do While Site.State <> ObjectState.Started
                Loop
            Next Site
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

This code gets all the way through the process without error, but it doesn't seem to actually make the necessary changes for the site to start using the new certificate. I manually restarted/refreshed the site from the IIS interface on the host, but it still doesn't seem to take effect. I've checked both the binding settings in IIS and the site itself (browser) and confirmed that it's still using the "old" certificate.

I've also tried to directly set the certificate hash of the `SiteBinding` object to the `X509Certificate2.GetCertHash` value, as well as assigning the `SiteBinding` object to the `NewBinding` object before trying to set the `CertificateHash` property as above. Unfortunately, both of these methods throw a `NotSupportedException` stating: `The specified operation is not supported when a server name is specified.`

Additionally, there are settings from the "live" `SiteBinding` object that can't be set on the `NewBinding` object (like the `.Host` property). All I really want to be able to do is to change the active certificate on that site and not muck around with any of the binding's other properties. The wording of the exception seems to indicate that what I'm trying to do can't be done remotely (at least, not with the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API), but I can't imagine that there isn't a way to accomplish this goal. I'm sure I'm simply missing/overlooking something here, but my Google-fu is failing me and I need to get this project functional as soon as possible.

### EDIT #1

I added the `Site.Stop()` and `Site.Start()` methods to restart the site from code, but it didn't make any difference. Plus, I'm sure there's probably a better way to implement that than what I've added to the code above.

### EDIT #2

I've refactored some things to align with the suggestion from Joel Coehoorn in the comments. The code above represents the current state but still produces the same result: No exception occurs, but I cannot get the bindings updated to use the new certificate, even though it's apparently added to the store.

Just to triple-check, I went to the site's bindings in IIS and the new certificate *does* show up as available to apply to the site. I know there's a lot of blur, but the one highlighted in blue is what I'm trying to apply to the binding:
[image: IIS 10 Site Bindings Dialog]

### EDIT #3

After reading Conrado Clark's Developer Log entry titled [Adding SSL Binding to a remote website using Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://conradoclarkdeveloper.com/2015/03/05/adding-ssl-binding-to-a-remote-website-using-microsoft-web-administration/), I decided to try to add the `NewBinding` to IIS instead of just updating the existing one:

```vb
    Site.Bindings.Add(NewBinding)
    Site.Bindings.Remove(SiteBinding)
    HostManager.CommitChanges()
```

This produced a different exception: `Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'binding' with combined key attributes 'protocol, bindingInformation' respectively set to 'https, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443:'`

So, I tried removing the existing binding first:

```vb
    Site.Bindings.Remove(SiteBinding)
    Site.Bindings.Add(NewBinding)
    HostManager.CommitChanges()
```

This time it made it through the first two steps (`Site.Bindings.Remove()` and `Site.Bindings.Add()`), but when it tried to execute `HostManager.CommitChanges()`, I got another "new" exception: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)`. Additionally, it "reset" the binding so there was no certificate installed on the site.

Just to see what would happen, I tried to commit the `Site.Bindings.Remove()` before trying to add it back.

```vb
    Site.Bindings.Remove(SiteBinding)
    HostManager.CommitChanges()
    Site.Bindings.Add(NewBinding)
    HostManager.CommitChanges()
```

The initial commit seemed to work fine (and the binding disappeared completely from IIS), but when it went to add the new binding, I got this: `The configuration object is read only, because it has been committed by a call to ServerManager.CommitChanges(). If write access is required, use ServerManager to get a new reference.`

I manually recreated the binding (*thankfully I had taken a quick screenshot before I started messing with it*), but that last error has given me an idea for my next attempt. I'm going to try to break the `Add()` and `Remove()` methods out to new methods where I can open new instances of the `ServerManager` object specifically for this purpose. I'll come back when I've had a chance to write/test that.

### EDIT #4

I tried the above and still ended up with an error stating that `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)`. So, just to see if I could determine the cause of the problem, I went to IIS and manually tried to apply the new certificate. I got the ***SAME EXACT ERROR*** from IIS! (*Yes, I know... I probably should have checked that bit a long time ago, but here we are*)

It looks like there's a problem with the certificate in the store. Digging around a little deeper, I found an [old reference on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ca6b41a-3afa-4f3d-a191-ddce842314e1/rtm-vista-problem-binding-an-ssl-certificate-to-an-ipport-nothing-works-?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) talking about this error being related to a missing private key. This makes it sound like I missed a step in the certificate installation process, so I guess I need to take another step back and figure out what's wrong with *that* method before proceeding.

Comment: fwiw, instead of returning True/False and a whole bunch of try/catch blocks in the `AddCertificateToRemoteStore()` method I would simplify the code by converting to a `Sub`, removing all the Try/Catch and Return statements, and letting any exceptions throw out to the caller. Then you have _exactly one try/catch block_ around the method itself, at which point the exception message is available to help with debugging. I say this, because I suspect something like this is happing when applying the bindings, but **the exception handling strategy is hiding the error.**

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to watch every step of the process since I'm unfortunately having to test this last step in the chain with a server that's actually "live". I'll try to do some refactoring and see if anything shakes out. Now that these certificates have successfully been installed in previous testing, there isn't much for the `AddCertificateToRemoteStore()` method to actually *do*, but I'm willing to try stuff. :P

Comment: The point was to use a different exception strategy for _both_ methods. If you want to the watch the process, letting the exception get thrown makes this _easier_, not harder.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying and truly appreciate the code review. I apologize for the miscommunication. I just had all of those `Try/Catch` blocks so I could quickly restart one block while I'm testing/debugging without going through the entire process again. I've done some refactoring as you suggested and have updated the post with the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

> a `NotSupportedException` stating: `The specified operation is not supported when a server name is specified`.

That's exactly what we should expect. Microsoft didn't develop that API to manage remote server's everything. As proof, you can see that even IIS Manager (built upon the same API) does not support managing server certificates of a remote machine.

If I were you, I will actually use other approaches, such as developing a dedicated small demon app to run on each IIS machines, so that actual communication via `Microsoft.Web.Administration` happens locally, not remotely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would tend to agree with that, except for the results of my testing - especially what happened in my **EDIT #3**. I can successfully remove the binding through code and the errors I'm dealing with now seem to indicate that I'm "hooking in" correctly. As stated in my **EDIT #4**, it looks like I'm having issues with the installation of the certificates themselves, so I'm actually hoping that finding the resolution to that issue will enable me to make some additional progress.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually gotten this working! As identified in my multiple **EDIT**s to the OP, it seems the main problem actually had to do with the original import of the certificate. Once that issue was resolved, everything else pretty much fell into place. I've provided the full working code at the end if you want the **TL;DR** version, but here's what I found:

## EXPLANATION/TROUBLESHOOTING

---

After a bunch of further research into the individual errors I encountered in my initial testing - specifically the `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.` error - I ran across this SO question: [IIS 7 Error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." when using https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70782579/2569697).

In the linked answer from user **naimadswdn**, they state that:

> I fixed it by running:
>
> `certutil.exe -repairstore $CertificateStoreName $CertThumbPrint`
>
> where `$CertificateStoreName` is store name, and `$CertThumbPrint` is the thumbprint of imported certificate.

Another answer to that same question from user **Ed Greaves** provides a bit of explanation for the underlying cause of the problem:

> This storage provider is a newer CNG provider and is not supported by IIS or .NET. You cannot access the key. Therefore you should use certutil.exe to install certificates in your scripts. Importing using the Certificate Manager MMC snap-in or IIS also works but for scripting, use certutil as follows:

The original question was asked about trying to import the certificate directly in IIS and, since my testing showed that I wasn't able to do that either, I went ahead and tried to repair the certificate from the command line on the server with `certutil`. I went back to IIS and, this time was able to successfully apply the certificate to the binding without error.

Since *that* worked, I reset the binding and tried again to set it to the new certificate through my code. No exception was encountered and, when I went to check the binding in IIS, it showed the correct certificate selected. I verified through my browser that it was showing the new certificate and everything seems to be working as expected/intended.

Of course, I want this process automated, so I can't be logging in to the server to repair certificates every 90 days. So, now I have two options:

1. Keep my existing code for adding the certificate to the store, then repair the certificate (as per **naimadswdn**'s answer), or
2. Take **Ed Greaves**' suggestion and use `certutil` to perform the actual import of the certificate.

Since I already have it importing the certificate into the store without any exception being thrown, I decided to go with the former solution (*for now, at least*). Of course, I want to do this remotely, so I've chosen to use WMI to execute `certutil` on the server (*see the `CertUtilRepairCertificateInStore()` method in the full code listing below*).

### (FINAL) TESTING

I reset the binding on the IIS site and deleted the certificate from the store to test my "new" process:

- The certificate was successfully added to the store by the `AddCertificateToRemoteStore()` method, but I paused execution before allowing it to "repair" the certificate in the store.
- While debugging was paused, I tried to manually apply the certificate to the binding in IIS. This resulted in the same `logon session does not exist` error.
- I allowed the `CertUtilRepairCertificateInStore()` method to run the `certutil` on the server through WMI. I didn't get any exceptions.
- I paused debugging again after the certificate was "repaired" and tried to manually apply the certifiate to the binding in IIS. Now the binding was successfully updated to use the new certificate.
- I manually reset the binding in IIS to use the old certificate and allowed my `ApplyCertificateBinding()` method to execute.

This time, the method completed without throwing any exceptions, so I went into IIS and verified that it does, indeed, have the new certificate applied to the appropriate binding. As one last bit of verification, I went to my browser and checked the certificate from the site itself and it shows the correct new ***Let's Encrypt*** certificate. It seems that, along with some other minor tweaks along the way, the `certutil -repairstore` call was the final solution.

## SOLUTION (CODE)

---

After all of that, I decided to keep my original code as-is and simply add the WMI bit to "repair" the certificate immediately after importing it to ensure it's ready to be applied to the binding. Yes, I could allow that to be handled in a `Try/Catch` block for the binding, but I'd rather just avoid the issue altogether. Here's a (mostly) complete listing of the functional code I'm using now and, so far, it seems to work exactly as I require/expect.

(***quick edit** - I moved the `HostManager.CommitChanges()` execution outside of the `For`/`Next` loop through the `HostSites` list because once the commit is executed, the code can't make any more changes until a new connection is opened.*)

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Web.Administration

Friend Async Function InstallSSLCertificate(ByVal PFXFile As IO.FileInfo) As Task(Of X509Certificate2)
    If PFXFile Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("PFXFile", "You must provide a valid PFX certificate file")
    ElseIf Not PFXFile.Exists OrElse PFXFile.Length <= 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("PFXFile", "You must provide a valid PFX certificate file")
    Else
        Dim CertPFX As X509Certificate2 = Nothing
        Dim CertSubject As String = String.Empty
        
        'THE GetOperationalCredentials() METHOD (not defined here) IS A CUSTOM UTILITY METHOD FOR RETRIEVING A SPECIFIC SET OF CREDENTIALS STORED ELSEWHERE
        Dim PFXCredentials As Net.NetworkCredential = GetOperationalCredentials(SecurityOperation.PFX)
        Dim UserCredentials As Net.NetworkCredential = GetOperationalCredentials(SecurityOperation.Server)

        If Not PFXCredentials Is Nothing Then
            'BUILD/EXTRACT THE X509Certificate2 OBJECT INFORMATION FROM THE PFX FILE
            'MAKE SURE TO SET THE X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet AND X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet FLAGS TO
            '  ENSURE THE CERTIFICATE PERSISTS IN THE STORE
            CertPFX = New X509Certificate2(PFXFile.FullName, PFXCredentials.SecurePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet Or X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet)
            CertSubject = CertPFX.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, False)

            If Not CertSubject Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CertSubject.Trim) Then
                If CertSubject.ToLower.Trim.StartsWith("ftps") Then
                    'THIS CONDITIONAL (not defined here) IS FOR HANDLING CERTIFICATE(S) THAT CANNOT BE INSTALLED FROM A CERTIFICATE STORE
                    If Not Await InstallSSLCertificateFromPEM(CertSubject, PFXFile, UserCredentials) Then
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not InstallCertificateFromPFX(CertPFX, UserCredentials) Then
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return CertPFX
    End If
End Function

Private Function InstallCertificateFromPFX(ByVal Certificate As X509Certificate2, ByVal Credentials As Net.NetworkCredential) As Boolean
    Dim Subject As String = Certificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, False)
    Dim Hostname As String = String.Empty
    Dim StoreName As String = String.Empty

    If Subject.ToLower.Trim.StartsWith("www") Then
        Hostname = "<WEBSITE_SERVER_NAME>"
        StoreName = "WebHosting"
    ElseIf Subject.ToLower.Trim.StartsWith("rdp") Then
        Hostname = "<REMOTE_DESKTOP_SERVER_NAME>"
        StoreName = "My"
    End If

    Try
        AddCertificateToRemoteStore(Hostname, StoreName, Certificate, Credentials)
        ApplyCertificateBinding(Hostname, StoreName, Certificate)
        'THE CleanUpCertifcateStore() METHOD (not defined here) IS SOMETHING I INTEND TO
        '  IMPLEMENT TO GET RID OF OLD UNUSED/EXPIRED CERTIFICATES
        CleanUpCertifcateStore(Hostname, StoreName, Certificate)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Connect to the remote certificate store and import the details from a valid <see cref="X509Certificate2"/> object
''' </summary>
''' <param name="HostName">The hostname of the server where the certificate store is located</param>
''' <param name="StoreName">The name of the certificate store into which the certificate should be imported</param>
''' <param name="Certificate">A valid <see cref="X509Certificate2"/> object containing the details of the certificate to be imported</param>
''' <param name="Credentials">A valid <see cref="Net.NetworkCredential"/> object for passing to the certificate repair method for establishing a WMI connection</param>
Private Sub AddCertificateToRemoteStore(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal StoreName As String, ByVal Certificate As X509Certificate2, ByVal Credentials As Net.NetworkCredential)
    If HostName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("HostName", "You must specify a server hostname")
    ElseIf StoreName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(StoreName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("StoreName", "You must specify a certificate store name")
    ElseIf Certificate Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Certificate", "A valid X509Certificate2 object is required")
    Else
        'SET UP THE PATHS TO THE APPROPRIATE CERTIFICATE STORES
        Dim CertStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\{1}", HostName, StoreName)
        Dim RootStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\Root", HostName)
        Dim IntermediateStorePath As String = String.Format("\\{0}\CA", HostName)

        'USE THE X509Chain OBJECT TO MAKE IT EASIER TO IDENTIFY THE APPROPRIATE STORE FOR
        '  EACH CERTIFICATE EXTRACTED FROM THE PFX
        Using CertChain As New X509Chain
            If CertChain.Build(Certificate) Then
                Dim FindResults As X509Certificate2Collection
                Dim StorePermissions As New StorePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)

                With StorePermissions
                    .Flags = StorePermissionFlags.OpenStore Or StorePermissionFlags.AddToStore
                    .Assert()
                End With

                For C = 0 To CertChain.ChainElements.Count - 1
                    If C = 0 Then
                        'FIRST ELEMENT IN THE CHAIN = CERTIFICATE FOR THE SITE
                        Using CertificateStore As New X509Store(CertStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With CertificateStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using

                        'REPAIR THE CERTIFICATE'S PROVIDER/PRIVATE KEY IN THE REMOTE STORE
                        CertUtilRepairCertificateInStore(HostName, StoreName, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate, Credentials)
                    ElseIf C = CertChain.ChainElements.Count - 1 Then
                        'LAST ELEMENT IN THE CHAIN = ROOT CA CERTIFICATE
                        Using RootStore As New X509Store(RootStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With RootStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using
                    Else
                        'ANY ELEMENT BETWEEN THE FIRST AND LAST IN THE CHAIN = INTERMEDIATE CA CERTIFICATE(S)
                        Using IntermediateStore As New X509Store(IntermediateStorePath, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
                            With IntermediateStore
                                .Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)
                                FindResults = .Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate.Thumbprint, False)

                                If FindResults.Count <= 0 Then
                                    .Add(CertChain.ChainElements(C).Certificate)
                                End If

                                FindResults.Clear()
                                .Close()
                            End With
                        End Using
                    End If
                Next C
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Use WMI to execute certutil.exe on the remote server to "repair" the certificate and correct issues with the provider/private key
''' </summary>
''' <param name="HostName">The hostname of the server where the certificate store is located</param>
''' <param name="StoreName">The name of the certificate store into which the certificate has been imported</param>
''' <param name="ActiveCertificate">A valid <see cref="X509Certificate2"/> object containing the details of the certificate to be repaired</param>
''' <param name="Credentials">A valid <see cref="Net.NetworkCredential"/> object for establishing the WMI connection</param>
Private Sub CertUtilRepairCertificateInStore(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal StoreName As String, ByVal ActiveCertificate As X509Certificate2, ByVal Credentials As Net.NetworkCredential)
    Dim WMIOptions As New Management.ConnectionOptions
    Dim WMIScope As Management.ManagementScope
    Dim GetOptions As New Management.ObjectGetOptions
    Dim WMIProcess As Management.ManagementClass
    Dim WMIParameters As Management.ManagementBaseObject

    With WMIOptions
        .Username = Credentials.Domain & "\" & Credentials.UserName
        .Password = Credentials.Password
        .Impersonation = Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        .Authentication = Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
        .EnablePrivileges = True
    End With

    WMIScope = New Management.ManagementScope(String.Format("\\{0}\root\cimv2", HostName), WMIOptions)
    WMIScope.Connect()

    WMIProcess = New Management.ManagementClass(WMIScope, New Management.ManagementPath("root\cimv2:Win32_Process"), GetOptions)

    WMIParameters = WMIProcess.GetMethodParameters("Create")
    WMIParameters("CommandLine") = String.Format("cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe -repairstore {0} {1}", StoreName, ActiveCertificate.Thumbprint)

    WMIProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", WMIParameters, Nothing)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Connect to IIS on a remote host to apply a new certificate to a site's SSL bindings
''' </summary>
''' <param name="HostName">The hostname of the server where the certificate store is located</param>
''' <param name="StoreName">The name of the certificate store into which the certificate has been imported</param>
''' <param name="ActiveCertificate">A valid <see cref="X509Certificate2"/> object containing the details of the certificate that has been imported</param>
Private Sub ApplyCertificateBinding(ByVal HostName As String, ByVal StoreName As String, ByVal ActiveCertificate As X509Certificate2)
    If HostName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("HostName", "You must specify a server hostname")
    ElseIf StoreName Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(StoreName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("StoreName", "You must specify a certificate store name")
    ElseIf ActiveCertificate Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("ActiveCertificate", "A valid X509Certificate2 object is required")
    Else
        Dim SSLSiteName As String = ActiveCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, False)
        Dim HostSites As New List(Of Site)

        Using HostManager As ServerManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(HostName)
            'FIND THE SITE(S) IN IIS THAT MATCH(ES) THE DETAILS FROM THE SSL CERTIFICATE
            '>>> THIS IS **FAR FROM** BULLET-PROOF, BUT I AM NOT SURE HOW TO MAKE IT BETTER <<<
            For Each Site As Site In HostManager.Sites
                If Site.Name = SSLSiteName Then
                    HostSites.Add(Site)
                Else
                    For Each Binding In Site.Bindings
                        If Binding.Host = SSLSiteName Then
                            HostSites.Add(Site)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next Binding
                End If
            Next Site

            For Each Site As Site In HostSites
                'USE THE .ToList() METHOD TO BASICALLY MAKE AN IN-MEMORY "COPY" OF THE
                '  BindingCollection OBJECT WHERE CHANGES CAN BE MADE WITHOUT MODIFYING THE
                '  COLLECTION ITSELF (which would cause the For/Next loop to generate an
                '  exception whenever any changes are made to the site's bindings)
                For Each SiteBinding In Site.Bindings.ToList
                    If SiteBinding.Protocol = "https" Then
                        If Not SiteBinding.CertificateHash.SequenceEqual(ActiveCertificate.GetCertHash) Then
                            'CANNOT JUST EDIT OR "REPLACE" AN EXISTING BINDING ON A REMOTE IIS HOST SO
                            '  CREATE A NEW BINDING TO ADD TO THE SITE AFTER THE EXISTING BINDING HAS
                            '  BEEN REMOVED
                            Dim NewBinding As Binding = Site.Bindings.CreateElement

                            NewBinding.CertificateStoreName = StoreName
                            NewBinding.Protocol = "https"
                            NewBinding.CertificateHash = ActiveCertificate.GetCertHash
                            NewBinding.BindingInformation = SiteBinding.BindingInformation

                            'THIS PROCESS MUST BE COMPLETED IN THIS ORDER
                            Site.Bindings.Remove(SiteBinding)
                            Site.Bindings.Add(NewBinding)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next SiteBinding

                'RESTARTING THE SITE IN IIS (there is almost certainly a better way to do this)
                Site.Stop()

                Do While Site.State <> ObjectState.Stopped
                Loop

                Site.Start()

                Do While Site.State <> ObjectState.Started
                Loop
            Next Site

            HostManager.CommitChanges()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm stepping into all of that from a method that looks for "pending" `.pfx` files that are waiting to be processd:

```vb
Private Async Sub CheckForNewSSLCertificates()
    Dim PendingSSLFolder As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\SERVER\Certify\PendingSSL\")

    For Each PFXFile As FileInfo In PendingSSLFolder.GetFiles("*.pfx")
        Dim CertPFX As Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 = Await InstallSSLCertificate(PFXFile)
        
        If Not CertPFX Is Nothing Then
            '[ARCHIVE THE PFX]
        End If
    Next PFXFile
End Sub
```

I know the documentation is a bit sparse but, if you find ways to make this more effective/efficient, or if you have any questions about what it's doing here, please feel free to let me know. Eventually I may try to just use `certutil` to import the PFX and one-shot that process, but for now I just wanted to leave this here for anyone else who's trying to implement some "centralized" automation for SSL certificate management.